# Getting "No more private agent slots available" attempting to add a new agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

From this link it appears that Agents have been renamed to Pipelines.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/get-more-build-or-load-testing-vs

It also states that "Private agents are now free and unlimited."  From Build & Release, Resource Limits, I show one free Pipeline.

We tried to add a second private agent to our VSTS and received the error:

"No more private agent slots available, please purchase more. For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=623705 Current max: 1  Xaml Controllers: 0  Build Agents: 1"

From the link above it'd appear we did what we needed to do and should be able to add aditional agents.  Any idea why we can't add an additional agent and Current max is 1?

Comment: What do you mean add a second private agent to VSTS? Do you mean you setup a new build agent or buy Private Pipeline? Provide the detail steps you did.

Comment: Per @Ed Blankenship below, it looks like there is a problem.  From Settings, go to "Agent Queues" and select "Download Agent" and attempt to use that agent you get the error.  We also have a post here on this topic. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b75f5df-1b71-44f4-89f7-ca5d5e41e80e/no-more-private-agent-slots-available?forum=TFService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  It looks like there is a problem with the logic so the engineering feature team is going to deploy a fix that should fix this problem.  You are right:  you can have unlimited agents and concurrent pipelines is what we are transitioning to charging for where pipelines can leverage multiple agents if needed.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Is there a timeframe on this being fixed? Is this being pushed to the server or will we need a new agent? This is blocking us as well so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Ed.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: BTW @Ed, is there a timeframe for the deploy of the fix?

Comment: @dwhittenburg I didn't get a timeframe back :(  It looks like they are on it though

Comment: Good to hear it's being fixed. Waiting on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have not switched from the agent-based model to pipeline model yet in Team Services. As we are still in the agent-based model, you will see this error if you have not purchased enough agents. We plan to switch to the pipeline model late January or early February.

Comment: Your published docs, the interfaces for resource limits and even how you purchase *pipelines* are all updated and in place. As the link in the original post states, Private agents are *now* free and unlimited. That document is still online. But apparently Now means 2 or 3 months after you announced Now?

Comment: @Vijay should we go ahead and purchase agents and then remove them once they become free in Jan/Feb?  Is there a more accurate date so we can prepare?