# No more private agent slots available, please purchase more. Current max: 1 Xaml Controllers: 1 Build Agents: 0

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, build, azure-devops

I'm getting this error below when trying to configure a Private Agent.

No more private agent slots available, please purchase more. For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=623705 Current max: 1  Xaml Controllers: 1  Build Agents: 0

I've checked and I couldn't find where to remove this XAML Controller. Where can I find it?

PS.: The link below says that MS is going to remove the XAML build support until March 2017, but I really wanted to remove it before, since we're going to migrate to VSTS before this date and I've got some work to do.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#im-looking-for-the-hosted-xaml-build-controller-where-did-it-go

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only see XAML controllers in the VS UI or the TFS Admin console on the machine where it is installed.  You can unregister it from there or simply delete it using the Manage Controllers action in VS.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, but I'm using the free plan for VSTS (should've mentioned early) and I couldn't find it. Guess I'll just wait MS team fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987001/getting-no-more-private-agent-slots-available-attempting-to-add-a-new-agent?noredirect=1#comment69257540_40987001) thread (asked 2 days ago), there is a problem with the logic so the engineering feature team is going to deploy a fix that should fix this problem.

BTW: You can’t remove Hosted XAML controllers.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT for your answer. Where will they send a notification when they fix this issue?

Comment: The Hosted Build Controller does not count against your private limit.